# Show checked rows into another DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, select, datagridview, datatable

I have a `DataGridView` populated with a `DataTable`.
I added a `CheckBoxColumn` to select some rows.

My Goal is to show only selected rows into another `DataGridView`

I tryed to accomplish this using `Select` and adding results to a new `DataTable` but `Select` doesn't work because `CheckBoxColumn` is missing.

Here's the code I used to fill 1st `DataGridView`and add a `CheckBoxColumn`:

```
Dim chk0 As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
With chk0
    .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.ColumnHeader
    .HeaderText = "Sel"
    .Name = "Sel"
End With
With Me.DataGridView1
    .Columns.Clear()
    .DataSource = DT_Events
    .Columns.Insert(0, chk0)
    .Columns("Event").AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
End With
```

Then, after checking some rows, I tryed to show the selected ones into another `DataGridView`:

```
Using DT_Checked As DataTable = CType(Me.DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable).Select("Sel = 1").CopyToDataTable
    If DT_Checked.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        With Me.DataGridView2
            .Visible = True
            .DataSource = DT_Checked
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox("No rows to show", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    End If
End Using
```

I tryed this code without `Select` and it doesn't show me `CheckBoxColumn`.
How can I fix?
How can I do it otherwise?

Comment: Please describe exactly the error/undesired behavior you encounter. `Select doesn't work` is not a sufficient description.

Comment: @AlexB. As in my question: "...doesn't work because `CheckBoxColumn` is missing" in the table `CType(Me.DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)`

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Add Boolean column as to bound SQL result](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32462308/1070452).  Filter one DGV to True, one to nothing at all or False

Comment: @plutonix It's a good tip but it's useful only if datatable is a query result

Comment: No, it just relies an using an underlying datatable and eitehr a DataView or the DefaultView filtering capability.  There is no need to copy data from one DT to another, just view it differently

Comment: @Plutonix Sorry for my previous comment: your suggestions are precious as ever, but I'm not yet able to use them (I'll study)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying rows to a new `DataTable` is wasteful because the only real difference between the two is whether some `Boolean` value is True or False.  Since you are binding to a `DataTable`, you can simply change the view displayed in each DGV.

The concept expressed in the title, ***show*** checked rows... is different than ***copying*** rows to another control as the code tries to do.  This will show how to use one `DataSource` to display some rows in each DGV.

**If your data comes from a database**, you can add a column in the SQL:

```
' Access version
Dim sql = "SELECT a, b, c, False AS Selected FROM SAMPLE"
```

This will add a Boolean Column initialized to False for all rows and will display in the DGV as a `CheckBox`.

**If the data gets into the DataTable some other way**, add the column manually:

```
dtSample.Columns.Add("Selected", GetType(Boolean))
dtSample.Columns("Selected").DefaultValue = False

' we need to loop and set a value
' if you manually add a column
For Each r As DataRow In dtSample.Rows
    r("Selected") = False
Next
```

To display rows in one grid (or listbox or combo) or the other based on that value, this code will use 2 `DataViews`.  If you are using views, you often want to change the `RowFilter` as you go, so make a few things global to the form:

```
Private dtSample As DataTable          ' base table for BOTH DGVs
Private dvSource As DataView           ' ALL or Selected = False view
Private dvDest As DataView             ' Selected only
...
' build datatable and add the Selected Row (if needed)
...
' create Source DV as Selected = False
dvSource = New DataView(dtSample, "Selected=False", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)

' create SELECTED DV as Selected = True
dvSelected = New DataView(dtSample, "Selected=True", "",DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)

dgv1.DataSource = dvSource
dgv2.DataSource = dvSelected
```

`dvSource` is optional.  If you want all rows to show in the first DGV, you that `DataView` (this appears to be the case as per the question).

For illustrative purposes, this is set up so that as items are checked in DGV1 they "disappear" from it (because they no longer meet the `Selected = False` criteria), and automagically appear in DGV2 (because, now they *do* meet that criteria. Results:

[image]

Rows unchecked/unselected in the bottom DGV will skitter back to the top one.

**It is economical**.  Not only do you not have to run any code at all to appear to add or move a row to the second DGV, but you are not making **copies of `DataRows`** and a new `DataTable`  to do so.  Going by `TaskManager` (rough, but indicative), the amount of memory stays about the same as Selected Rows change; when manually copying them, it slowly creeps up as you make copies of `DataRows` containing the same identical data.

Comment: Compliments and thank you! This is an exhaustive explanation that gave me the opportunity to improve my code. Surely I'll use in the future

Answer (score 1):

I propose that you add column "Sel" as `Boolean` in your datatable "DT_Events" .
Change your first code to :

```
 DT_Events.Columns.Add("Sel", GetType(Boolean))
  DT_Events.Columns("Sel").SetOrdinal(0)
With Me.DataGridView1
    .Columns.Clear()
    .DataSource = DT_Events
    .Columns("Event").AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
End With
```

And the seconde code will work with copying the selected row into  "DataGridView2"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the data table **DT_Events** doesn't have the column **Sel**, select takes the datasource of the grid i.e the data table you assigned.

Instead of adding a checkboxcolumn, add a boolean column **Sel** in the table **DT_Events** and assign to grid.