# How to add a line in a dataview from the original datatable

Tags: vb.net, datatable, dataview

I have a question about adding a line in a dataview. I'll use an example to explain.
My program fills a datatable with all clients (20 clients). I then created a `dataview` which I filter using the property `"RowFilter"`. There are still 10 clients in the `dataview`. I then bind it to a `datagrid` (Telerik).
Now I have a button that allows me to add a client in this datagrid. The client can only be a client available in the source datatable.
My question is, can I add a line to my existing `dataview` without add the line in the `datatable` (the opposite of delete)? Should I change the property `"RowFilter"`?

Otherwise, I thought of creating a String variable containing the list of all ClientsID I want to `display (strClient = "10,11,12")` that I use in the `"RowFilter"` like this `'ClientId IN (strClient)'`. When a client is added, I will update this variable and updates the property `"RowFilter"` which will add my client in `dataview`.
What do you think?
Thank you in advance.
Seb

Comment: `The client can only be a client available in the source datatable.`  If the record is in the DataTable it is also in the DataView, so yes you need to change the filter property.  `What do you think` I think if you added the relevant code, you'd be more likely to get an answer

Comment: Rather than filtering using `IN (...)` you could add a `Selected` column to the datatable and set that to true for those you want to show and filter on it.

Comment: Your solution with the `Selected` column is perfect. Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: There is an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37121085/1070452

Comment: this is exactly what I did (the addition of the `Selected` column and then  the use of a `dataview`). Thank you for the example.