# VB.NET How to remove selected rows from DataTable and update it to CheckedListBox?

Tags: vb.net, datatable, visual-studio-2015, dataview, checkedlistbox

First I set up the DataTable as shown below. Added 3 columns with Desc, Price and The full string to display.

```
    checkBoxDT = New DataTable
    checkBoxDT.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With
                   {.ColumnName = "Desc", .DataType = GetType(String)})
    checkBoxDT.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With
                   {.ColumnName = "Price", .DataType = GetType(Decimal)})
    checkBoxDT.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With
                   {.ColumnName = "DisplayText", .DataType = GetType(String),
                   .Expression = "Desc + ' - RM ' + Price"})
```

Then, I create a new dataview and bind the CheckedListBox1 to the DataTable.

```
    checkListView = New DataView(checkBoxDT)
    checkListView.Sort = "Desc ASC, Price ASC"
    CheckedListBox1.DataSource = checkListView
    CheckedListBox1.DisplayMember = "DisplayText"
```

Here I add new items to the CheckedListBox1 with the code below

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim quan As Integer = 0
    Dim currentPrice As Decimal = 0.0
    If ComboBox2.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
        quan = Convert.ToInt32(ComboBox2.Text.Trim())
        currentPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(TextBox3.Text.Trim())
        For i As Integer = 1 To quan
            checkBoxDT.Rows.Add({ComboBox1.Text, Convert.ToDecimal(TextBox3.Text)})
            totalItems = totalItems + 1
            totalPrice = totalPrice + currentPrice
        Next
    Else
        currentPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(TextBox3.Text.Trim())
        checkBoxDT.Rows.Add({ComboBox1.Text, Convert.ToDecimal(TextBox3.Text)})
        totalItems = totalItems + 1
        totalPrice = totalPrice + currentPrice
    End If
    TextBox5.Text = totalItems.ToString()
    TextBox4.Text = totalPrice.ToString()
End Sub
```

But I am having problem in deleting the CheckedListBox1 items. Here is what I have tried.

This is the delete button. I am trying to delete the items in CheckedListBox1 for all the selected items. Then show the right price in TextBox4. When I select only 1 item to be deleted, it works fine. But multiple item selected does not work properly. It deletes other item which is not selected as well.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim currentPrice As Decimal = 0.0

    While CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count > 0
        currentPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(CType(CheckedListBox1.SelectedItems(0), DataRowView).Item("Price").ToString())
        totalPrice = totalPrice - currentPrice
        totalItems = totalItems - 1
        checkListView.Delete(CheckedListBox1.SelectedIndex())
    End While


    TextBox4.Text = totalPrice.ToString()
    TextBox5.Text = totalItems.ToString()
End Sub
```

Comment: try this:http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2010/09/22/how-to-delete-selected-items-from-a-checkedlistbox.aspx instead of delete use remove

Comment: @coder32 I have seen the guide already. Still not able to do what I want so I posted a question here.

Comment: [Show checked rows into another DataGridView](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37113690/1070452)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example where the DataSource is a DataTable. Any checked items are removed at the DataTable.Rows level.

```
Dim dtSource As DataTable = CType(CheckedListBox1.DataSource, DataTable)
Dim theItems As CheckedItemCollection = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems
Dim rows As New List(Of DataRow)

For Each cItem In theItems
    Dim row = CType(cItem, DataRowView).Row
    rows.Add(row)
Next

For Each r As DataRow In rows
    dtSource.Rows.Remove(r)
Next
```

Second version with count and sum

```
Dim dtSource As DataTable = CType(clbCheckedListBox.DataSource, DataView).Table
Dim theItems As CheckedItemCollection = clbCheckedListBox.CheckedItems
Dim rows As New List(Of DataRow)

For Each cItem In theItems
    Dim row = CType(cItem, DataRowView).Row
    rows.Add(row)
Next

Dim Total As Decimal = rows.Select(Function(row) row.Field(Of Decimal)("Price")).Sum
Dim Count As Integer = rows.Count

Console.WriteLine($"Total: {Total}")

For Each r As DataRow In rows
    dtSource.Rows.Remove(r)
Next
```

Comment: I get an error at `dtSource` : `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataView' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'.`

Comment: Dim dtSource As DataTable = CType(clbCheckedListBox.DataSource, DataView).Table

Comment: I managed to fixed that but I also want to know how to get the current checked item "Price" because I want to minus from the total price as well. Something like `currentPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(rows(r)("Price").ToString())`

Comment: See my revised reply, second example.

Comment: Thanks so much! I managed to get the current checked item price by doing this as well : `currentPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(r.Item("Price").ToString())`. Anyway your answer did help to fix my issue. Thanks again!