# Query Datagridview and output to Datagridview vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

I just want to make sure I am reading microsoft's documentation correctly, and that I understand the structure appropriately.

First here is link I am reading:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669099(v=vs.110).aspx

Second here is the code they suggested:

```
' Create a table from the bound view representing a query of 
' available products.
Dim view As DataView = CType(bindingSource1.DataSource, DataView)
Dim productsTable As DataTable = CType(view.Table, DataTable)

' Set RowStateFilter to display the current rows.
view.RowStateFilter = DataViewRowState.CurrentRows

' Query the DataView for red colored products ordered by list price.
Dim productQuery = From rowView As DataRowView In view _
                   Where rowView.Row.Field(Of String)("Color") = "Red" _
                   Order By rowView.Row.Field(Of Decimal)("ListPrice") _
                   Select New With {.Name = rowView.Row.Field(Of String)("Name"), _
                                .Color = rowView.Row.Field(Of String)("Color"), _
                                .Price = rowView.Row.Field(Of Decimal)("ListPrice")}

' Bind the query results to another DataGridView.
dataGridView2.DataSource = productQuery.ToList()
```

Sorry if this seems like a dumb question, but my inquiry is mainly related to understanding how to query it appropriately. The "SELECT" part of this code is at the end, correct? (i.e. Select New With, column_name, column_name etc etc). Sorry to put it in SQL terms but I was wondering if it was more efficient to query a datagridview (kind of using it like a temporary table for a query) than having to either reach back out to DB or loop through contents to check for so and so variable.

And is "bindingSource1" the first datagridview, or the source data (table in db)?

Comment: You could probably do what you want more simply just using the RowFilter:  Filter to Color Red and Order by price.

Comment: For sure, but my endeavor is to learn new tricks. The idea is learning how to query datgridviews, or an easier way to move specific information from one datagridview to another.

Comment: There usually isnt a need to clone a datasource to show data in another DGV - just use a different view of the base data.

Comment: But that's what I am asking about? Either way my question is more pertaining to whether or not I understand the concept correctly....

Comment: The MSDN (partial) example seems to be unaware of the actual datasource other than it is wrapped in a BindingSource (no, thats not the DGV).  Are you dealing with TableAdapters and typed DataSets or DB Provider objects in general?  When it comes to efficiency, there are simpler ways to go about filtering, sorting and even showing some of the data in a different control

Comment: Well I was thinking about an interactive datagridview with checkboxes,textboxes, comboboxes etc etc and being able to query those and moving them to new dgv's based on contents. Like I said earlier, just trying to learn new things. If you have another method of moving this to another display then feel free to let me know. I just thought being able to query it would be faster performance wise  @Plutonix

Comment: With a bound DGV, it is simply displaying a VIEW of the data to the user.   Thinking of it in terms of querying the DGV makes it more difficult.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37121085/1070452) shows how to use views on *one* datasource to show selected rows in one, UNselected in another.

Comment: Nice thread. I think that is helpful. Though I am not entirely sure this is what im after, I do think it helps me understand a better way of approaching the situation. Honestly, I wasnt too sure of what I was after since i am just playing around to see what can/cannot be done, however I think it was a worthwhile endeavor. Sorry tinkering around to learn more...

Comment: Well, if it is helpful, do feel free to upvote it.  The same thing could be done to *appear* to copy the Red rows to a different DGV.