# problem with fitting datagridview height according to the content

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview whose styling is kept as follows

```
dgvCreatinine.AutoGenerateColumns = False
        dgvCreatinine.AutoSize = False
        dgvCreatinine.AutoResizeRows()
        dgvCreatinine.AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
        dgvCreatinine.AutoResizeRows(DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCellsExceptHeaders)
        dgvCreatinine.DataSource = dtTemp
```

It is appearing as shown in the attached image

[image]

As you can see the gridview is not resizing to the content along row wise. Could someone tell me how this can be accomplished? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really need the datagridview to change height? Or could you just change the `BackGroundColor = Control` (or same color as your form) to simulate that effect?

Comment: @djv I really want datagridview to change height, either grow or shrink. Width should be fixed  (width should not move)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show checked rows into another DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37113690/show-checked-rows-into-another-datagridview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set the height of the entire control using this formula

> DataGridViewHeight = HeaderHeight + NumberOfRows * RowHeight

Code:

```
dgvCreatinine.Height =
    dgvCreatinine.ColumnHeadersHeight _
    + dgvCreatinine.Rows.OfType(Of DataGridViewRow).First().Height * dgvCreatinine.Rows.Count()
```

This *works*, but could use some tweaking. For example, there may be a better way to get the row height. And you may also need to add a pixel or two depending on borders. Also, if you have an underlying DataSource, you could get the rows count from it.

That code should be called whenever a row is added or removed, or DataBindings are updated etc.